# Resizing Images In Jquery Soon After Adding To The DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, dom, resize

I'm doing something like this:

```
maxDim = 100;
$('div.images').html('<img class="pull" src="'+imgs[img_i]+'" />');
$('img.pull').each(function(i){
  if( $(this).height() > $(this).width() ){
    var h = maxDim;
    var w = Math.ceil( $(this).width() / $(this).height() * maxDim);
  }
  else{
    var w = maxDim;
    var h = Math.ceil( $(this).height() / $(this).width() * maxDim);
  }
  $(this).css({height:h, width:w});
});
```

Now I'm pretty sure that the image resizing part is just fine ... esp since it matches up with this answer http://adeelejaz.com/blog/resize-images-on-fly-using-jquery/

The problem that sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.  (it will show up still native resolution at times and resized on others)  It seems that timing is the real issue here.  Maybe the resizing gets called before the image is actually in the DOM to select it again right after?  Any advice you guys have would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the images are not loaded yet sometimes. In that case the original size is still unknown (0) and the calculation leads onto NaN-values because of division by zero.

Resizing when the load-event  of the images fires should be an option.

Comment: Ahh, that sounds like it might be it, let me try it out.

Comment: +1 for responding fast and having the true source of the problem, I'll mark your answer as correct although I wish I could give it to you and Mark Eirich

Answer (score 2):

You will need the [special image load event plug-in](https://github.com/peol/jquery.imgloaded/raw/master/ahpi.imgload.js). Otherwise, the event will not fire if the image is already in the browser's cache. Then you can do this:

```
$('img.pull').load(function(i){
    // ...
});
```

Comment: Do I have to worry about the fact that I'm adding the image to the dom and may need .live() ??

Comment: I would assume that the plugin will work just as well with .live(). The usage would be `$('img.pull').live('load', function(i) {});` ...I have not tested it yet.

Comment: It wasn't firing on live (I tried just how you did it) ... so what I did is started off with an img tag with an empty src ... then changed its src dynamically instead of messing with the DOM

Comment: +1 For some amazing advice/help got through it all.  I gave Dr. Molle the correct answer b/c that was the fundamental problem I was experiencing.  However without your help I would have also ran into this issue.  I wish I could accept both, Thank You!